# Error with advanced query code 1064 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting an error when I try to do the below query:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID WITH C.CustomerName WITH O.OrderDate WITH O.TotalOrderAmount
FROM CUSTOMERS C
LEFT JOIN [ORDERS] 0
ON C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID

UNION

SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, O.OrderDate, O.TotalOrderAmount
FROM CUSTOMERS C
RIGHT JOIN [ORDERS] 0
On C.CustomerID-O.CustomerID;
```

Below is the code that I am receiving in MySQL:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[ORDERS] 0 ON C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID  UNION  SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerN' at line 3
```

Any assistance that can be provided to correct this error is highly appreciated.

Comment: WITH? Shouldn't you use a comma there?

Comment: And remove those brackets.

Comment: The last line should have an `=` sign, not an `-`, right?

Comment: Can the alias of a table be a digit `0`? I guess you meant a letter `O`, right?

Comment: Square brackets are for MS SQL Server. MySQL has back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

A table alias cannot be a number.  And `with` is not the same as `as`.  Try this version:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, O.OrderDate, O.TotalOrderAmount
FROM CUSTOMERS C LEFT JOIN
     [ORDERS] o  -- not 0
     ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
UNION
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, O.OrderDate, O.TotalOrderAmount
FROM CUSTOMERS C RIGHT JOIN
     [ORDERS] o  -- not 0
     On C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID;  -- not -
```

I should also mention that this is not the best way (in my opinion) to formulate a `full join`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a Full Join instead of union-ing a left & right join?

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . MySQL doesn't support `full join` (historically).

Answer (score 0):

Just do a full join instead of a union.  Should give you the same results here:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, O.OrderDate, O.TotalOrderAmount
FROM CUSTOMERS C
full JOIN [ORDERS] 0
On C.CustomerID-O.CustomerID
```